# Error 500: Laravel and Angular 4 Invalid header name type; expected string; received integer

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5.4

I have a backend using laravel 5.4 and a frontend with Angular 4, there's a error that I couldnt find, I dont know if is a backend or frontend problem.

When I want to get a list of 'convocatorias' is through this route:

http://localhost:8000//api/administracion/configuraciones/convocatorias/?cantidad=6&page=1   => It is working good on postman

But, when I click on button 'Buscar' on frontend there's a random 500 error :

[image].

I print the name variable on the HeaderSecurity.php assertValidName function and here are the results:

With error: hostconnectionacceptoriginauthorizationuser-agent0

Without error: hostconnectionacceptoriginauthorizationuser-agentcontent-typerefereraccept-encodingaccept-language

Is an Angular problem or is Laravel? Please explain the correct way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Post your code where you think its triggering the error.

Comment: hmm, could you take a look on `HeaderSecurity.php` and `MessageTrait.php`? Can't find it in the vanilla Laravel repository.. perhaps it is custom.

Comment: I found that function called assertValidName($name) when I print the name value I get the next headers...                                                    
With error: hostconnectionacceptoriginauthorizationuser-agent0

Without error: hostconnectionacceptoriginauthorizationuser-agentcontent-typerefereraccept-encodingaccept-language  In others modules is working well but in others I get that error, I think is frontend which  is using the InterceptorService, when try to enter in the laravel route doesnt receives any information...